# My wooden Fakro attic ladder is not trimmed properly according to manual. How dangerous is it to use?

Tags: attic, ladder

It says that when unfolded, the metal arms attaching the top segment to the door frame should be resting on and supported by the two adjustment bolts in the door frame, the feet should be flush to the floor and each segment should sit flush with each other, no gaps - perfectly straight in other words. The problem is that together, the segments are too long for the ladder to be completely straight and with the connecting top arms resting on the adjustment bolts at the top. I can unfold it so that the ladder is straight but not touching the bolts, but as soon as I put weight onto the middle segment, the door will continue to open until the top arms hit the bolts, opening a gap between the top and middle segments.

I could extend the bolts so that it supports a fully straightened ladder at a shallower angle, but the problem there is that it would be extended beyond the maximum 3/8" specified in the manual.

Physically, is it much safer to trim to the correct length? Or will trimming it not make a difference compared to its current state or extending the bolt beyond its 3/8" to get a shallower angle? If I were to trim it, the manual says to trim the middle segment near the bottom joint, and I don't know if it's worth all that trouble.

[image: top arms resting on bolt]

[image: gap between top and middle segments when top arms supported by adjustment bolts]

[image: top arm not supported by bolt when ladder completely straight]

Comment: I would trim the bottom section of the stair.  Note that many attic stairs come with short extension pieces that can be added to make up for room height or installation differences.  This is sort of the opposite of your problem, but the situation is similar.  The as-delivered stair length is too long (your case) or too short (my example) for a given installation.

Comment: A distant photo,  would help in understanding the problem better.  But as above, if the stairs are too long, trim them.